# Gradle 5.0 causes error Val cannot be reassigned when using Kotlin DSL in buid.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, kotlin

This error did **NOT** occur in gradle version 4.10.2

The line `classDirectories = files(filesToCover)` causes gradle to throw an error:

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 80:             classDirectories = files(filesToCover)
                       ^ Val cannot be reassigned
```

But when you look at the underlying Java class `JacocoReportBase` you can clearly see that there's a setter and the class property is not final.

```
public abstract class JacocoReportBase extends JacocoBase {
    private FileCollection executionData;
    private FileCollection sourceDirectories;
    private FileCollection classDirectories;
    private FileCollection additionalClassDirs;
    private FileCollection additionalSourceDirs;

    ...

    public void setClassDirectories(FileCollection classDirectories) {
        this.classDirectories = classDirectories;
    }
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile<KotlinJvmOptions>> {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    withType<JacocoReport> {
        reports {
            xml.isEnabled = false
            csv.isEnabled = false
            html.destination = file("$buildDir/jacocoHtml")
        }

        afterEvaluate {
            val filesToAvoidForCoverage = listOf(
                    "/dto",
                    "/config",
                    "AuthenticationMicroServiceKt.class"
            )
            val filesToCover = mutableListOf<String>()
            File("build/classes/kotlin/main/app/example/core/")
                    .walkTopDown()
                    .mapNotNull { file ->
                        var match = false
                        filesToAvoidForCoverage.forEach {
                            if (file.absolutePath.contains(it)) {
                                match = true
                            }
                        }
                        return@mapNotNull if (!match) {
                            file.absolutePath
                        } else {
                            null
                        }
                    }
                    .filter { it.contains(".class") }
                    .toCollection(filesToCover)

            classDirectories = files(filesToCover) // error
        }
    }
}
```

I have also posted an issue in Github [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1265)

Comment: `val` needs to be `var` in order to resign it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at [the source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/java/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/JacocoReportBase.java#L121-L138):

```
/**
 * Source sets that coverage should be reported for.
 */
@PathSensitive(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)
@InputFiles
public ConfigurableFileCollection getClassDirectories() {
    return classDirectories;
}

/**
 * Classes that coverage should be reported for.
 * @deprecated Use {@code getClassDirectories().setFrom(...)}
 */
@Deprecated
public void setClassDirectories(FileCollection classDirectories) {
    DeprecationLogger.nagUserOfDiscontinuedMethod("JacocoReportBase.setClassDirectories(FileCollection)", "Use getClassDirectories().from(...)");
    this.classDirectories.setFrom(classDirectories);
}
```

As you see, `getClassDirectories` has return type of `ConfigurableFileCollection` and `setClassDirectories` accepts `FileCollection`. So this is not a valid Java Beans property, because getter and setter operate on different types. So only getter is seen by Kotlin and it is, actually, a `val`.

You can either try to call `setClassDirectories` directly (`setClassDirectories(…)` instead of `classDirectories = …`), or to use `classDirectories.setFrom`, as suggested by the Javadocs.

It worked in 4.10.2 because it [was a property at that time](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.10.2/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/java/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/JacocoReportBase.java#L108-L119) (getter and setter types were the same). Things changed in [this commit](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/76fecd4f823a1108f0044a2269aad92383a6660e).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Used `setDynamicFeatures` for `dynamicFeatures` after upgrading to Arctic Fox and Java 11.